# AJAX call to refresh values without reloading page doesn't show new values all the times

Tags: ajax, django, django-views

I am building an auction project and in template I am making an AJAΧ call when form submitted from template to view in order to reload the page without refreshing but something is wrong sometimes. Although call is successful, new values aren't shown all the times although altered in database. When i hit F5 new values are shown.

live-auction-details.html

```
         <form id="bid" >{% csrf_token %}
              <input id="auction_id" type="hidden" value="{{ auction.id }}">
              <button type="submit">Bid</button>
          </form>

<script>
$('#bid').on('submit', function(event){ //bid is the name of the form

    $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '{% url 'auction:live-auction-details' auction.id %}',
        data: {
            auction_id: $('#auction_id').val(),
            csrfmiddlewaretoken: $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val(),
        },
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
});
```

views.py

```
def live_auction_details(request, pk):

try:
    auction = Auction.objects.get(id=pk, status=1)
except Auction.DoesNotExist:
    raise Http404("auction not found")

if request.method == 'POST':

    // update records in database


if request.user.is_authenticated():
    # can user bid ?
    if request.user.player.credits >= auction.credit_charge:
        player_can_bid = True

    # is player registered ?
    if AuctionPlayers.objects.filter(auction_id=auction, auction_player_id=request.user.player.id):
        player_is_registered = True

context = {
    'auction': auction,
    'player_can_bid': player_can_bid,
    'player_is_registered': player_is_registered,
}
return render(request, 'auction/live-auction-details.html', context)
```

Comment: I noticed you are returning a rendered template to the ajax call. Shouldn't you be returning JSON data?

Comment: Yes I will give it a try and let you know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What AJAX does is an asynchronous request to the server, and it will send a response depending on whether or not it could complete the action that is required. To update the values, you must do it manually, since it is not something in "real time" so to speak.

If the request had a successful response, then you must update the fields of the view in the success function.

For example:

```
$.ajax({
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'your_endpoint',
  data: your_data_object
  dataType: 'json', // If you are using an API RestFul
  success: function(response) {
      // Here you have to update your view in order to show the changes
      // This is an example code
      $("#input").val(response.newValue);
  }
});
```